# How to set right for user to stop iis application pool

Tags: iis-7.5, cruisecontrol, nant

I log on `CruiseControl.net` service with user in one domain (`DOMAINNAME\user`).
and I want to use nant script to stop application pool on other server.

and I got this error

```
Failed stopping application pool '***********' on '172.16.0.62'.
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I can stop it if i set this user to be admin on that server but i don't want to.
anyone have any solution for this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are doing the app pool manipulation in your nant script, but if you call [msdeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) to do it, you can pass credentials into msdeploy of a user that has permission to stop the app pool.